# How to update timestamps (createdAt and updatedAt) specific index in mongoose without changing times of other items present in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have two schema LicenseSchema and UserSchema. A user can have multiple licenses which is nested in key app.

But when i try to push any license into the licenses it changes the updatedAt for all the licenses for that user and all the updateAt has the same value.
Even if we don't have any change in the license which is already present.

Lets take an example.
License at index 0 has value

```
    {
        licensecode: '12345',
        expiringAt: '2022-03-23T10:37:07.656+00:00'
        createdAt: '2021-03-23T10:37:07.656+00:00',
        updatedAt: '2021-03-23T10:37:07.656+00:00'
    }
```

But when we push a new license at index 1 updateAt of index 0 should not change but for some reason mongoose automatically recalculate timestamps for all the items present in the licenses Array.

I tried `update()` with `$push` and `save()`. In both the cases it actually updates the timestamps of the other items present in the array.

**I just want to update the createdAt and updatedAt for the item which i am pushing in.**

```
const LicenseSchema = new Schema({
  licensecode: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    sparse: true,
  },
  expiringAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
},{
    timestamps: true
});

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    sparse: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
  app: {
    licenses: [LicenseSchema],
  },
});

const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id });

user.app.licenses.push({
    licensecode: data.license,
    expiringAt: data.expiryDate,
});

await user.save();
```